# java receive and concatenate file from more threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a problem. I would like to send file partialy in 4 sockets, where every socket is connected with 1 thread. Protocol which I'm using is TCP. I think that when I'm sending file I send it on sockets in good order. But I've problem on the side where I receive the bytes and try to concatenate it to the file.
Here is my thread code for receiving bytes from socket.

```
long i = fromIdx;
         //file.seek(fromIdx);
         while (i < fromIdx+partLen) {
            int arrSize = ((i + 1000 > fromIdx+partLen) ? (int)(fromIdx+partLen-i) : 1000);
            byte[] data = new byte[arrSize];
            input.read(data);

            synchronized(file) {
                System.out.println(i);
                file.seek(i);
                file.write(data);
                //fromIdx = file.getFilePointer();
                i += arrSize;
            }

        }
```

file is of type RandomAccessFile. The main problem is that some bytes in result are zeros. I think that other are in good order. I realy don't know where the problem can be. Maybe some synchronize problem when seek set filePointer somewhere where it shouldn't be, but I realy don't know...

Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: Are you sure that each read returns number of bytes you expected? This is not guaranteed (or even typical) in case of TCP. Always check return value of `read`.

Comment: I had the same problem dude, use `DataInputStream#readFully(byte[] arr)` which ensures you it fills up the array and return, or exception if EOS, or not enough data is available.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`InputStream.read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int):

> Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of
>   bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller
>   number may be read. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer.

You should always chceck return value of `read`, as it's not guaranteed (and, in case of TCP sockets, even not typical) to read the number of bytes that it's expected to.